# How to get data from database into a table (Angular 8, C#, WebApi)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do something relatively simple but I'm confused by all the options and I need your help.

I'm trying to retrieve information from a database, pass it through an API and display it within a table I made in Angular.
The idea is to get all the productivity whose status is 1 into some list. Return the list to Angular and display the data in a table.

I know there are many options. Admittedly all the examples I tested are in Angular and C # projects as I should. But each project is different from the other and no example matched the way my project is structured.

So that's my code: (I know a lot of details are missing and it's not perfect
so I need help)

**messages.component.html**

```
<table id="customers">
                    <tr>
                        <th>productivity num</th>
                        <th>user ID</th>
                        <th>amount</th>
                        <th>Special comments</th>
                        <th>Accept/reject</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of productivityList">
                        <td>{{item.ProductivyCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.UserCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.ProductivityNum}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Cmment}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <button class="button is-success">accept</button>
                                <button class="button is-danger">reject</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**messages.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/shared/services/user.service';
import { Productivity } from 'src/app/shared/models/productivity';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages',
  templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css']
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private userservice: UserService) { }

  productivityList: Productivity[];

  ngOnInit():void {
   this.getProductivityRequest();
  }

  getProductivityRequest() {
    this.userservice.getProductivityRequest().subscribe((res) => {
      this.productivityList = res;
      if (res)
        console.log("ok")
    },
      err =>
        console.log("faild")
    );
  }
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { Productivity } from '../models/productivity';
import { Time } from '@angular/common';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
//import { read } from 'fs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  url: string = "https://localhost:44387/api/User/";
  productivityList: Productivity[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProductivityRequest() {
    return this.http.get(this.url+'getProductivityRequest');
}
```

**UserController.cs**  //that's my project in C#

```
using BL;
using DTO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebApiSystem.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    [RoutePrefix("api/User")]

    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getProductivityRequest")]

        public IHttpActionResult GetProductivityRequest()
        {
            return Ok(UserService.GetProductivityRequest());
        }    

    }
}
```

**UserService.cs**

```
using DAL;
using DTO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BL
{
    public class UserService
    {
        public static IQueryable<dynamic> GetProductivityRequest()
        {
            using (Model2 db = new Model2())
            {
                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                IQueryable<dynamic> PList = db.ProductivityTbl.Select();//I want to make a condition within the SELECT that only an object whose status 1 will enter the list
                return PList;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I hope it was clear enough and that maybe you can show me how to write the code correctly and if anyone has another idea like returning a JSON object I would love for you to show me how to do it... thank you!

Comment: seems all is correct, what your API return when you test it with postman ?

Comment: OK simple check, just output the results from your http call in your component. you have OK in the "log", output "res", do you get anything? If you don't fire up Postman and make the same http call and check the response object for errors.

Comment: Okay he gives me the following error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44387/api/User/getProductivityRequest' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

He gave me this problem also a previous time when I did another function. The problem then was that the attribute was not well placed but now I do not know what is wrong

Comment: Hi, you can resolve the CORS issue by configuring the behaviour in the Configure() method of your Startup class within the web api....  added as an answer below to display the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

To resovle the CORS error when calling web api from an Angular front end, you can configure the behaviour in the Configure() method of your Startup class within the web api...

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Ben, I appreciate ...
I apologize for the ignorance I'm pretty new to it and I'm not sure I understood exactly where I'm supposed to write the method you suggested.

Comment: In a web api project, you should have a file called Startup.cs which is generally used to configure the asp.net processing pipeline and register services for dependency injection.  That file will contain the Startup class which probably already defines the Configure() method.  You will likely just need to add the line for "UseCors".

Comment: Well I checked, and I do'nt have such a file.

Comment: I suggest you create a new Web API project using the Visual Studio wizard and review the generated files.You should see Startup.cs next to Program.cs in the project folder.

Comment: I tried to open a new project and still did not see the above file there. I tried to add it manually but could not implement the interface.